# Call method chain in the middle of existing method chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I `send` the result of one method chain to the method chain I'm using?

For example:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @collection = @resource.sub_resources.send(index_scope).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
  end  


  private

    def index_scope
      MyModel.approved.today
    end
end
```

The `index_scope` returns a chain of scopes for the appropriate model. Is there any way to chain those scopes in place of where I call `send(index_scope)` in the `index` method? The `send(index_scope)` is not working, it's just my latest attempt.

Another option I thought of was to put the scope names in an array and then call each one in succession. That would mean `index_scope` changes to:

```
def index_scope
  [:approved, :today]
end
```

Which would change the method change to:

```
@collection ||= @location
  .send(controller_name)
  .tap do |o|
    index_scope.each { |method| o.send(method) }
  end
  .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: per_page)
```

But I'm wondering if Ruby has a better way.

Comment: I'm very curious about what `mine` does. Your model layer typically should not have any knowledge about the user making requests.

Comment: It's just an example scope. I'll change the name to avoid confusion. It doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) two scopes together:

```
def index
  @collection = @resource.sub_resources.merge(index_scope).paginate(...)
end

def index_scope
  MyModel.approved.mine
end
```

Comment: This is nice, but doesn't `merge` override other scopes? This page says "If we do want the last where clause to win then Relation#merge can be used." http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: @flyingL123 Yes, but only when identical.  If you merge `where(a: 1)` and `where(b: 1)` together, you'll (effectively) get `where(a: 1, b: 1)`. But, if you merge `where(a: 1)` and `where(a: 2)` together, you'll just get the last one, `where(a: 2)`. This is because the alternative, `where(a: 1, a: 2)` is nonsensical and can never match any rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying. I had been misinterpreting that documentation for a while and always avoided `merge` when it was actually exactly what I needed.

Comment: `merge` is actually quite useful, and actually prevents the serious problem where merging two scopes that apply mutually exclusive conditions to the same field would always yield 0 records.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @collection = scoped_for_index(@resource.sub_resources).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
  end  


  private

  def scoped_for_index(collection)
    collection.approved.mine
  end
end
```

Comment: The only caveat I would add is that, if both scopes have conditions applied to the same value, chaining scopes in this way will `AND` the conditions together, while `merge` will overwrite the conditions with the last one specified.

Comment: What makes this the best compared to the one I accepted? I think using `merge` is nicer, and then I don't have to pass the collection to another method.